# Failure to update innerhtml of panel in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to show legends in Panel but it's showing an error while updating panel's innerhtml

```
Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference
```

I have written down the following code for this

```
document.getElementById('LegendsList').innerHTML = LegendsList;
```

Comment: Are you sure you've got an element with id: LegendsList?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?

Panel has a config option that you can use to render the required markup in its body so you don't need to fiddle with elements.

It is `html:'<b>your markup</b>'`

If you need to set it at runtime, call `panel.setHtml('<b>your markup</b>')`

Comment: Assuming panel here is an instance of Ext.panel.Panel the method `panel.setHtml()` seems to be undefined when I test it and I can't see it in the docs for [ExtJS 4](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel) or [ExtJS 5](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel)

Comment: Perhaps you meant `panel.update(...)` as that seems to work for me. Here is the [api ref](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-update)